# Can WCF service receive messages, if SOAP message from client doesn't contain service Identifier/URI

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a WCF service that should be able to receive the request form 3rd party client, whose request are compatible with SOAP 1.1

The request from the 3rd part 
POST / HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/ITestService/Hello
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: 100.10.1.104:8000
Content-Length: 297
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close
...

My WCF service is able to identify the request only when the URI/service identifier is specified in the POST request.
i.e.  POST /MyTestService/TestService HTTP/1.1
Can a WCF service receive the request if URI is not specified? How to achieve this?

thanks